# How to "Save to Files" on iphone?

Tags: iphone, video, vlc

From time to time, I may airdrop a video file to one of my iphones. Then I use the following procedure to get the video file viewable with the VLC app.

1. Navigate to the video file I have just airdropped to the iPhone, in the Photos app.
2. Select it.
3. Press the "share/action" button (the one with the up arrow), to get a range of action choices as well as apps that can open the file.
4. Look for something like "Save to Files" with the Files app icon, and tap on it.
5. Select "On My Phone" as the location to add the item (other choices may includ iCloud Drive, Google Drive, etc.).
6. After I do that, I am able to use the VLC app, select the file and open/play it.
7. I may delete the original video file from the Photos app.

The question I'm asking, is, on at least one iPhoneX, there is no option to "Save to Files", even though I have the Files app visible in my home screen. So I can't figure out how to do step 4, and cannot use VLC to open/play such files, on just this iPhoneX.

Any idea why this is so? Is there a way to configure some setting somewhere to make "Save to Files" become an option on this iPhoneX? I looked in Settings, and can't find something in Files app settings. Navigating around the Files app also didn't help me to find such a setting.

Here's an example from an iPhone6 on iOS 12.1.4 (16D57). Due to privacy concerns, I am only attaching the lower half of the screen capture.
[image: lower half of screenshot]

Comment: Files is a *manager* app, it’s not a destination.

Comment: Hmm .. how would files being a manager app explain why "Save to Files" appears in some iPhones and not in others?

Comment: I’ve seen “save file” but not “Files”.  This wouldn’t vary by device.

Comment: I've added a screenshot from another phone to show what I mean. On yet another phone, an iPhone SE 2nd generation, the ability to "Save to Files" or "save file" is no longer there. I'm not sure if something changed during the last iOS update That phone is on iOS 14.6

Comment: is there three dots and "More" in the choices on your phone? if you scroll options away. But I have yet another old iOS.

Comment: Ummmm... If your goal is to play a video with VLC why not use VLC's built-in web based uploader? I haven't done that is quite a while, but a quick check shows that it is still available. And it would bypass all these issues with "saving to file/files."

Comment: @Andra Yes, I have pressed the three dots to search there too. The result is still the same - the option to "Save to Files" is in some iPhones and not in others. I wonder if it was removed from a certain version of iOS onwards.

Comment: @SteveChambers Thanks, I will try that. At first I thought it may need internet connectivity while playing, but a quick check seems to indicate that I have be wrong about that. Still, it may be nice to know what's going on with saving to "Files".